# datepicker and maskmoney not work on dynamic table (added by) jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datetimepicker

I'm trying to make a dynamic table, where user may add or remove row using jquery.

In my table, there is a field for an input with datepicker and another with maskmoney.

i'm using 
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker
For datetimepicker

and https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/ For maskmoney.

My function for datetimepicker is :

```
$('.datepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    clearButton: true,
    weekStart: 1,
    time: false
});
```

For default row :

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="stuff-table">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>QTY (pcs)</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." name="name-1" id="name-1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="..." name="date-1" id="date-1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." name="price-1" id="price-1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." name="qty-1" id="qty-1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add_row" type="button" class="btn bg-green btn-xs waves-effect">
                    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td colspan="6">
                <button class="btn bg-blue btn-xs btn-block wave-effects">
                    <i class="material-icons">save</i> SAVE
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#price-'+i).maskMoney({thousands:'.', decimal:',', precision:0});
            $('#qty-'+i).maskMoney({thousands:'.', decimal:',', precision:0});
        });
    </script>
```

everything work fine on the first load, but, when other row(s) generated with jquery, datepicker and maskmoney not work.

Here's my function to add new row :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var row             = parseInt($('#stuff-table tr').length)-2;
        var increment       = row+1;
        var tr_open         = '<tr>';
        var td_increment    = '<td>'+increment+'</td>';
        var td_name         = '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." name="name-'+increment+'" id="name-'+increment+'" /></td>';
        var td_date      = '<td><input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="..." id="date-'+increment+'" name="date-'+increment+'"></td>';
        var td_price        = '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." id="price-'+increment+'" name="price-'+increment+'"></td>';
        var td_qty          = '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." id="qty-'+increment+'" name="qty-'+increment+'"></td>';
        var tr_close        = '</tr>';

        $('#stuff-table tr:last').before(data);

        var data            = tr_open+td_increment+td_name+td_date+td_price+td_qty+tr_close;


        $('#price-'+increment).maskMoney({thousands:'.', decimal:',', precision:0});
    </script>
```

anyone know why ? is there any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

==========================================================================

I solved this case with simple way.
Just add function to call back moneymask and datetimepicker after data append in table.

here's the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var row             = parseInt($('#stuff-table tr').length)-2;
            var increment       = row+1;
            var tr_open         = '<tr>';
            var td_increment    = '<td>'+increment+'</td>';
            var td_name         = '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." name="name-'+increment+'" id="name-'+increment+'" /></td>';
            var td_date      = '<td><input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="..." id="date-'+increment+'" name="date-'+increment+'"></td>';
            var td_price        = '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." id="price-'+increment+'" name="price-'+increment+'"></td>';
            var td_qty          = '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="..." id="qty-'+increment+'" name="qty-'+increment+'"></td>';
            var tr_close        = '</tr>';

            var data            = tr_open+td_increment+td_name+td_date+td_price+td_qty+tr_close;

            $('#stuff-table tr:last').before(data);


            $('#price-'+increment).maskMoney({thousands:'.', decimal:',', precision:0});

            $('.datepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                clearButton: true,
                weekStart: 1,
                time: false
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I struggled with datetime picker too, it was hard to integrate in my code? Why? because my concept to which jquery and what not to include and after who?.. So what I did was I made two programs. firstly just run the simple datepicker program, remove everything else. when you're done with sorting out you head tag and script tag (also do change jquery,bootstrap versions play with it, ascend descend their order until it working single handedly), then try to integrate with your program, make sure now your program doesnt have any other scripts that conflict with your current date time picker script

Comment: Also you can send us what errors you get in console

Comment: @BILALMALIK , i solved the problem, and i have no error before, so the problem only function of those two need to re-call.

Comment: it could be better if you post the answer also for those who wants to know it, perhaps anybody in future might end up searching for this exact question.